# Able to read childByAutoId but not custom named nodes?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read the child "Arts & Humanities" by reading:

```
Database.database().reference().child("posts")
//NOT WORKING
```

[image]

However it's not working. However, when my data is structured like the image below, it works
[image]

NOTE: I'm avoiding coding it like:

```
Database.database().reference().child("Arts & Humanities)
```

since there are other Childs on this level that I need to read (i.e "Science")

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is little unclear to me on what you are attempting to read. Can you please rephrase & describe the full structure and which nodes you are trying to read? - If possible avoid any special characters in the collection/node names (characters like $ - not allowed) (we can avoid many errors).

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem? Please see our comments and answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a bit hard to understand your question and issues (”Not working” is of little help).

However, the following code allows you to iterate over the children of ”posts”.

```
let dbRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: ”posts”)
dbRef.child(”Arts & Humanities”).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    // Iterate over auto ids 
    for id in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

        // Print the id
        print(id.key)

        // Get the value of id children like this
        let genre = id.childSnapshot(forPath: ”genre”).value as? String
        // ...and so on
    }
})
```